# CSS - How can I center a div within a div?

Tags: css

I have an outer div that is 800px wide.  I have an inner div that could be anywhere from 200 to 600px wide.

I know how to center the inner div within the outer one if I set the inner one to have a specific width, but how do I center it since its a variable width?

Is there a way to set the div to only be the width of the elements inside of it, rather than having it expand to fill its containing div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating, display:inline-block, or absolute positioning will shrink-wrap a div. Of those, display:inline-block would be the easiest to center with a simple text-align:center. If you have to support crappy browsers (I'm sure you do), [check this out](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).

Assuming you aren't supporting FF2 still, you can actually do away with most of the hacks, and still support older IE's by making the inner div a span instead. display:inline-block works on older IE as long as the element was originally an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set a width on the inner `div`, otherwise it's implicitly going to take up the whole width of the outer `div`. If you mean "dynamic width" as in "floated", it'll be really tricky to center it.

So, assuming you do set a width on the `div`, just add this style:

```
.centeredDiv {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;  // auto left/right margin will center it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the X and Y co-ordinates of the innerDIV, whenever you want to re-align the innerDIV.
EG:

innerDIV.style.left = (outerDIV.style.width-innerDIV.style.width)/2

innerDIV.style.top = (outerDIV.style.height-innerDIV.style.height)/2

where innerDIV is style is set to `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

You can make three css classes with appropriate margin so taht div willl be in center & apply these classes on the basis of width of inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Table hate is all the rage these days, but I find that using a table with cells set to percentage widths solves this problem cleanly (and is cross browser):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"></td>
    <td>centered content</td>
    <td width="50%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```